# Vuejs - reading data from table

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to pull an updated value out of the table below to send it to database, but it appears that Vue does not support two-way data binding. Could anyone give me a hint on how I extract the current cell value and pass it to a function saving new data to a database?

```
<table v-if="tableData.length > 0" class="table table-bordered table-sm">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">#</th>
    <th scope="col">Date From</th>
    <th scope="col">Date To</th>
    <th scope="col">Days</th>
    <th scope="col">Type</th>
    <th scope="col">Request Date</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="(object, index) in tableData" :key="index">
    <th scope="=row"><label class="tableNumberColumn">{{index + 1}}</label></th>
    <td @change="readData" v-for="(value, key) in object" :key="key" v-if="key != 'formId'">
      <div @change="readData" class="container tableColumnDiv" v-if="key === 'numberOfDays'" contenteditable="true">{{value}}</div>
      <div class="container tableColumnDiv" v-else-if="key === 'timeOffType'" contenteditable="true">{{value}}</div>
      <div v-else>
        <datepicker :value="value" :bootstrap-styling="true"></datepicker>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <b-button @click="deleteRow(index)" class="btn btn-sm buttonDelete">Delete</b-button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <b-button @click="update(index)" class="btn btn-sm buttonUpdate">Update</b-button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <b-button class="btn btn-sm buttonPrint">Print</b-button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: just to make sure i understand then you click on `update` function you get the current index of `tableData` array then get that object to send it using ajax ?

Comment: When I click the update button I want to do several things: 1) Read the currrent value inside a cell (which I don't know how to do using Vuejs) 2) Get the index of an object in a row 3) assign a new value to that object in tableData collection 4) finally send a new object to update a database

Answer (score 0):

I am pasting the code one more time as I've removed some unnecessary stuff:

```
<table v-if="tableData.length > 0" class="table table-bordered table-sm">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">#</th>
    <th scope="col">Date From</th>
    <th scope="col">Date To</th>
    <th scope="col">Days</th>
    <th scope="col">Type</th>
    <th scope="col">Request Date</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="(object, index) in tableData" :key="index">
    <th scope="=row"><label class="tableNumberColumn">{{index + 1}}</label></th>
    <td v-for="(value, key) in object" :key="key" v-if="key != 'formId'">
      <div class="container tableColumnDiv" v-if="key === 'numberOfDays'" contenteditable="true">{{value}}</div>
      <div class="container tableColumnDiv" v-else-if="key === 'timeOffType'" contenteditable="true">{{value}}</div>
      <div v-else>
        <datepicker :value="value" :bootstrap-styling="true"></datepicker>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <b-button @click="deleteRow(index)" class="btn btn-sm buttonDelete">Delete</b-button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <b-button @click="update(index)" class="btn btn-sm buttonUpdate">Update</b-button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <b-button class="btn btn-sm buttonPrint">Print</b-button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: check this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/5rye1k80/12/) i've made a small test in how to update/delete from array

Comment: Thank you. The problem  is that I don't know how to pass NEW data from the table provided by a user to update the object. In case of your example, this would be 'updated  of test object' value. How do I get that value from DOM and pass it to the update function using Vuejs?

Comment: That new value you get it from `<datepicker>`  ?

Comment: <datepicker>  plus all the other cells. The table is editable. It presents the data currently stored in a database, but it is also supposed to allow a user to edit the values and update the database.

Comment: check this https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1670 for contenteditable